# SELECT query inside PostgreSQL transaction commits data even with ROLLBACK

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to wrap my head around transactions in PostgreSQL compared to MSSQL. I want to test out some update commands and then roll them back, with `SELECT` queries sprinkled inbetween the `UPDATE` commands to confirm that the results are what I expect. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE my_table SET int_column = 1 WHERE id = 1;

-- i want to check that the column has been set to 1
SELECT * FROM int_column WHERE id = 1;

-- i want to rollback the updates while testing
ROLLBACK;
```

What is confusing to me is that the `SELECT` query seems to be committing the update, even with `ROLLBACK` as the last statement. If I remove the `SELECT` the rollback prevents the update as expected, though if I leave it in there the column is actually updated! I must be missing something here because in MSSQL `SELECT` queries can be used inside transactions without this issue.

I couldn't find any details about this via searching or on the [PostgreSQL Transaction Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html).

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? Did you enable auto-commit?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using one called Postico, I can't find any options referring to auto-commit in it

Comment: Maybe it simply doesn't support the `BEGIN ... ROLLBACK` transaction control. Your example will work properly in `psql`

Comment: https://github.com/jakob/Postico/issues/257 no need to quote Jakub here, but I think the author Postico has his own opinion :)

Comment: @Martin-Brennan try running your code in any other client but Postico?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `psql` instead of Postico and my issue was resolved, seems like Postico doesn't support this functionality!